# Associative Selection from the Table in to Asp.net application form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one table in a de-normalized form Named 'Category Classification' in which i have 4 fields like Category, Subcategory, Brand and Company.

I want to develop a searching criteria on asp.net in which the scenario would be:

- If i select category from the drop down, It should automatically show the subcategories associated with that selected category in the next drop down of the subcategory.
- Same goes for the brand as well. If i select the subcategory, The grid should appear with the check boxes of the related brands of that selected subcategory.

The screen shot of the said criteria is attached along.

I need the logic behind the denormalized database like Microsoft excel has that functionality which i need to implement on asp.net.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to use Javascript, Jquery and Ajax in this situation. post what codes have you written so we can help

Comment: Hi icedragon, there is no primary and foreign key so i cannot retrieve the data easily ,the data is de normalized data

Comment: This is a windows form not ASP isn't it?

Comment: yes, but this is a window form but i am re develop the asp.net again

Comment: As I mentioned before you have to use several technologies to achieve this. It's can't be answered here. Start your project and post the exact issues that you face

Comment: my issue is dropdownlist1 is category and dropdownlist2 is subcategory i have select the category to automatic selection on subcategory but there is no selection on same time

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the linked drop down lists goal, here is a link that explains the issue in details and solve it without using Jquery and Ajax
[Creating Cascading DropDownLists is ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: sir this topic i was seen but there is normalized data but my data is de normalized my data is no primary key and foreign   key to how to resolve the criteria

Comment: normalized or not normalized this affects the query that you use, it doesn't affect the front-end codes and tools